What is a consistent way to fund(airdrop) to new accounts on devnet in your Anchor test program?
I have the following typescript anchor test code that requests airdrops and works well in localnet.
//Airdrop SOL to intialize accounts
it("Airdrop", async () => {
  await Promise.all([admin, studentA, studentB].map(async (k) => {
    await connection.requestAirdrop(k.publicKey, 100 * anchor.web3.LAMPORTS_PER_SOL).then(confirm).then(log);
  }))
});

But once the program is deployed on devnet it mostly fails for the following reason. Is there a better way to fund test accounts on devnet every time the test runs ?
Server responded with 429 Too Many Requests.  Retrying after 500ms delay...

You could use always the same keypair that already has sol.
For that you can for example use the Solana Helpers:
https://github.com/solana-developers/helpers/blob/main/src/lib/keypair.ts
If you need a new funded keypair you could transfer some sol from a funded keypair.
But for tests is probably better to run them locally anyway.
